# Will Allah will give a deaf & dumb person like me the gift of hearing and speaking after second world?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, disability

I am deaf mute and use British sign language. I am a Muslim brother.

After I die, I am in my grave and Allah will give me hearing and speaking after second world?

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you shall be able to hear and see in the ākhirah.

Comment: Not only in akhirah but also in the grave when Munkar and Nakir ask their questions. There is also the concept of the soul visiting the places of Illiyin & Sijjien before being sent to its grave. But I'm not sure about the blessings of being able to hear and talk there.